# C++ Explain "one liner" constructor that overloads member function Iterator(int i = 0) : i(i) { };

Tags: c++, constructor, ctor-initializer

I have a question about what this contractor is actually doing. I found it online and it works for my purpose, but I wish to understand its notation.

```
class Iterator { 
  int i;
public:
  Iterator(int i = 0) : i(i) {};

  friend class SinglyLinkedList<Element>;
  Node* _current;

  Iterator(SinglyLinkedList& list) {
    this->list = list;
    reset();
  }

  void reset() {
    _current = list._head;
  }

  void next(){
    if(!done()) {
      _current = _current->_next;
    }
  }

  bool done(){
    bool done = false;
    if(_current->_next == nullptr) {
      done = true;
    }
    return done;
  }
private:
  SinglyLinkedList list;
};
```

This is a member function that proves it works.

```
unsigned long print(Element e, const Iterator& index) {
cout << index.i << "\n";
return 0;
```

When `const Iterator& index = 2`. The function outputs 2.

If you ignore the part about `Element e`, the basic idea is that I can use `Iterator(SinglyLinkedList& list)` and `Iterator(int i = 0)`, both. And you can access the integer attribution by using `index.i`?

Any general insight is also appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about `Iterator(int i = 0) : i(i) {};`  ?

Comment: Yes. Its a complicated constructor.

Comment: `int i` unless you have noticed correctly, is not a public or private member of your class - you can access it simply by `.` opearator. It is open for acess/mutation to everyone. And `i(i)` bit is initialising the parent class constructor for `int`.

Answer (score 4):

The constructor

```
Iterator(int i = 0) : i(i) {}
```

lets you construct an instance of an iterator in three ways:

- You can use this constructor without passing arguments (in which case zero is assumed)
- You can call this constructor explicitly, passing it a single `int` argument, or
- You can call this constructor implicitly, passing an `int` instead of it.

Here is the first way:

```
Iterator one;
```

Here is the second way:

```
Iterator two(123);
```

Here is the third way:

```
Iterator three = 321;
```

Back to your code, when you write this

```
const Iterator& index = 2;
```

the compiler creates a temporary object, initializes it using the implicit invocation of your constructor, and sets the reference of this temporary object into `index`. This is similar to the third kind of invocation of the constructor (i.e. the implicit one) but the target is a hidden, temporary object. The compiler is allowed to use a temporary here, because the `index` is declared `const`; it wouldn't compile without it.

Answer (score 0):

[dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26723696/3457753)
 explains the different ways this can be used, but I want to talk about what's actually going on here.

The line is `Iterator(int i = 0) : i(i) {};` Let's break down all the pieces.

`Iterator(int i=0)` does three things:

1. Announces that this is a constructor for the `Iterator` class
2. Announces that this constructor takes a single `int` argument
3. Provides a default value for the single argument. In other words, the constructor calls `Iterator()` and `Iterator(0)` will have the same result

`: i(i)` is an initializer list. It assigns the member variable `i` (That's the first `i`) to the value of the parameter `i` (The `i` in brackets).

`{};` is the body of the constructor. Nothing else is happening here, so it's been left empty.

A more verbose way of writing the same thing would be the following:

```
Iterator(){
    i = 0;
}

Iterator(int index){
    i = index;
}
```

That block and the line you've provided will have essentially the same result in most cases, although I don't know enough about the intricacies C++ to know if the above will work for some of the interesting cases you have (Like `const Iterator& index = 2`)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was possible to assign arguments to member variables.